# Configurable rules for a user for a Java Back End App

Tags: javascript, java, graph, analytics, rules

In our project we have a requirement.
Assume we have some performance metrics available to each node in a graph.Let those metrics be c1,c2,c3 etc.

Now there can be rules like below based on which our app calculates the  the score for each node(in a graph) and aggregates the scores of all nodes and returns the aggregated score to the user.

```
if(c1>10 and c2<20) score=c1+c2 else score=2*c1;
```

These rules should be configurable for each request by the user from a UI or text file.This  might look like some kind of analytics.

We were thinking of using javascript for this kind of rules which can be defined by the user.Now we can take this javascript and invoke it from java.And this rule is executed for many nodes in a graph where in the nodes can be 1000+.Javascript Rhino might be slow compared to a pure java execution and that too for 1000+ invocations of javascript from java for each request.

I looked at other options like xtext etc where in either the user or we can configure the rules.I am not able to decide how do the analytics applications provide such a kind of configurable UI to define rules and how their back end handles those.What can be a reasonable approach for this kind of scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Drools http://www.drools.org/

Comment: Do all nodes in same graph use same rules during aggregation or it is possible that different nodes use different user defined rules ?

Comment: @user3360241  Yes.Same rules.

Comment: @itsme But it shud be configurable by an end user.And drools is much of a task for this functionality.

Comment: I have done something similar before. Basically, you should define simple language for this and give to client some very simple grammar (syntax) for your language. You have a bit more work parsing and translating the input, but idea is that client gets some simple intuitive syntax. When client enters input, you verify that it meets grammar and if it does feed it into 'compiler' for that language. As long as these expressions are not something super complicated this should not be to hard to do. Also, here is a link to Expression Trees which might be helpful: http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=600

Comment: @user3360241 ok.That will be implementing something from scratch.Might be if this is one of the ways then rather than implementing the whole stuff,we can user xtext which does the parser ,lexer etc generation.I was trying to understand how the analytics organizations  provide configurable query's based on parameters in the UI.

Comment: @user3360241 they might be rolling out their own dsl for the query language.